# Is there a way to set default day in strtotime("YYYY-mm")

Tags: php, time

Following snippet is in my project:

```
/*
//forget it 
$ts = 1319990400;
$y = date("Y",$ts);
$m = date("m", $ts);

var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$y-$m")));
*/
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-1"));
```

it return

```
"2013-01-10"
```

In this [post](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#96095), it says default day is 1st in a month. But I found it outputs **2011-10-10**!! I move snippet to a clean PHP script, it outputs 2011-10-01 normally.

I think it is some option about strtotime to set a default day? I also find today is 10th does it matter?

**update**: I know just add full date format like "$y-$m-01" can solve problem, but I want to know why it happen?

**update**: It's so weird. I just write date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-1")) and it return "2013-01-10"

**update**: update my answer. :)

Comment: Are you sure you are outputting the right code? Maybe the result comes from a different one? I tested your code and it gave me `string(10) "2011-10-01" `

Comment: yeah,that's the problem, I move that code to a new script that outputs result as same as you. But it doesn't work as well in my project. So I think there is some code naughty.

Comment: Do an echo of the `$y` and `$m` variables before the var_dump and see what's in them.

Comment: $y=='2011' $m=='10'. That's not problem,dude.

Comment: If you say it works in a clean document, then try to simply move `var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2013-1")));` up your code until it's something different. That way you'd figure out **what** line actually makes the difference, and you could answer your own question, so others could find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what happen guys.

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

My project use PHP 5.2.4, in this version, strtotime will set $now's day as default day. I set $now to many different value to confirm this. But I can't find any information about this in strtotime() change log.

By the way, the clean script use PHP 5.2.17.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 1st, you can just do this:

```
$ts = 1319990400;
var_dump(date("Y-m-01", $ts));
//string(10) "2011-10-01"
```

Comment: I know how to avoid this and it does work well. But I want to know why it outputs this or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php) in PHP >= 5.2

```
<?php
$ts = 1319990400;
$dateTime = new DateTime;
$dateTime->setDate(date('Y', $ts), date('n', $ts), 1);
var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2011-10-01"
var_dump($dateTime->getTimestamp()); // int(1317474597)
```